# Add quotation marks to listings

Tags: listings, code, quotation

I've seen that this question has already been asked a while before but that solution didn't help me, maybe it's because of the new version or something. So, the problem is that I want quotation marks to show up in my listings which show my C++ code because I want the printing of the output to be seen.

Here is my listing:

```
 \begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,label=lst:rssfeeder,title=Пример 5]

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Sledeca funkcija - display_matrix vrsi ispis matrice  
// povezanosti na standardnom izlazu
void display_matrix(int** matrica, int v) {
   for(int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < v; j++) {
         cout << matrica[i][j] << " ";
      }
      cout << "\n";
   }
}

void add_edge(int** matrica, int a, int b, int w) {       
   matrica[a][b] = w;
}

// Glavni deo programa u kome se vrsi ucitavanje broja cvorova (v) i grana (e),       
// nakon cega se koriscenjem funkcija formira i ispisuje matrica povezanosti
int main(){
 int e,v,a,b,w;
 cout << "Uneti broj cvorova: ";
 cin >> v;
 list<int> lista[v];
 cout << "Uneti broj grana: ";
 cin >> e;

 int** matrica = new int*[v];
 for(int i=0; i<v; i++)
    matrica[i] = new int[e];

 for(int i=0; i<e; i++){
   cin >> a >> b >> w;
   add_edge(matrica,a,b,w);
  }

 display_matrix(matrica,v);
}

    \end{lstlisting}
```

And here are all the libraries that I have included:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,serbian,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[serbian]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
```

If anyone knows the answer it would be much appreciated because I need to finish my work very very soon, thank you

Comment: I have compiled your code and it works. Is your distribution updated?

Comment: Okay, that's very weird, I am doing everything on Overleaf, I thought that it automatically updates everything. I am totally confused as to what I should do now.